# pl/sql Function XMLType.EXTRACT doesn't work in Oracle Forms 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, xmltype

I need to parse an xml file with an Oracle forms (11.1.2.2) program and I want to use XMLType package.

First, this sample program works well in PL/SQL Developer:

```
  declare

  table0 XMLType :=XMLType('<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <table>
    <name>PARAM_TEST1</name>
    <columns>
      <column>
        <name>CODE_PARAM</name>
        <type>VARCHAR2</type>
        <size>3</size>
        <pk>Y</pk>
        <visible>Y</visible>
      </column>
      <column>
        <name>DESC_PARAM</name>
        <type>VARCHAR2</type>
        <size>25</size>
        <pk>N</pk>
        <visible>Y</visible>
      </column>     
    </columns>
  </table>');
v_count NUMBER(38) := 1;
begin
  WHILE table0.existsNode('//column[' || v_count || ']') = 1 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(table0.extract('//column[' || v_count || ']/name/text()').getStringVal());
    v_count := v_count + 1;
  END LOOP;    
end;
```

In Oracle Forms, I create this sample package:

```
PACKAGE pkg_sample IS
  table0 XMLType := XMLType('<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <columns>
            <column>
                <name>CODE_PARAM</name>
                <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                <size>3</size>
                <pk>Y</pk>
                <visible>Y</visible>
            </column>
            <column>
                <name>DESC_PARAM</name>
                <type>VARCHAR2</type>
                <size>25</size>
                <pk>N</pk>
                <visible>Y</visible>
            </column>           
        </columns>');
```

After I create a program unit to search the column names in XML file

```
PROCEDURE pr_load_column_info IS
        l_count NUMBER(38) := 1;
        result varchar2(1000);
    begin
          WHILE pkg_sample.table0.existsNode('//column[' || l_count || ']') = 1 LOOP
            result := pkg_sample.table0.extract('//column[' || l_count || ']/name/text()').getStringVal();  
            message('loop '||l_count||' - '|| result);
        l_count := l_count + 1;
      END LOOP;    
end;
```

**With the above code my forms application crash !**

Now if I create the following database function:

```
create or replace function fn_get_xml_value(p_xml_data XMLType, p_XPath varchar2) return varchar2 is
  Result varchar2(1000);
begin
  Result := p_xml_data.extract(p_XPath).getStringVal();  
  return(Result);
end fn_get_xml_value;
```

And if I call it in forms :

```
PACKAGE BODY Generic_data IS
        PROCEDURE pr_load_column_info IS
            l_count NUMBER(38) := 1;
            result varchar2(1000);
        begin
              WHILE pkg_sample.table0.existsNode('//column[' || l_count || ']') = 1 LOOP
                result := fn_get_xml_value(pkg_sample.table0, '//column[' || l_count || ']/name/text()');
                message('loop '||l_count||' - '|| result);
                l_count := l_count + 1;
              END LOOP;    
        end;

END
```

**it is working fine**

The only difference is the execution of the following line is done on database side:

```
result := pkg_sample.table0.extract('//column[' || l_count || ']/name/text()').getStringVal();
```

Any idea ? Is it due to the PL/SQL Engine in forms ?

Thanks

Comment: Likely PLSQL engine in Forms does not support this function. The way you have worked around by adding this code to the database is the usual trick.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll keep it like this.

Answer (score 0):

As reply by TenG, lack in forms pl/sql engine, code should be added in DB.